# Make datagridview to read from inside objects

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
  class A{
  int a;
  B b;
  }
  class B{
  int c,d;
  {
  .
  .
  .
  List<A>list = new List<A>();
  Populating list with object....

  BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
  dataGridView1.Update();
  bindingSource.DataSource = list;
```

Is it possible to force dataGridView1 to show 3 columns which will contain values from int a,c,d 
without creating new class and copying data from class A to new class?

Comment: you can specify binding columns

Comment: and how can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataGridView colums allow to bound only to first-level properties.

If its not big program, or if u on the modeling stage of writing easier is to make new class where all items are in first-level.

But if u really need that model please read this:

[TypeDescriptionProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2007/01/19/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-column-to-a-second-level-property-of-a-data-source.aspx)

That should help you making what u want, but for smaller programs (or if its really not necessary) faster and easier is first method ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to force dataGridView1 to show 3 columns which will contain values from int a,c,d without creating new class and copying data from class A to new class?

You could use a DataTable.  Set up your columns, then iterate through the list and add each element of each A as a new row in the DataTable.  Then use the DataTable as DataSource for the DGV.

Seems to me though that using a listview would accomplish the same thing.

Another alternative is make b private and in A have public properties, which echo the properties in b.  This way all the properties you want are first level